# UIAlertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler shows warning "the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined"

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

When i try to present a alertController with textfeild using addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler, i got warning:

```
2015-12-14 11:03:32.022 TestAlertWithTextField[8455:1172878] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2015-12-14 11:03:32.022 TestAlertWithTextField[8455:1172878] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2015-12-14 11:03:32.023 TestAlertWithTextField[8455:1172878] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is , and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}> collection view layout: .
2015-12-14 11:03:32.023 TestAlertWithTextField[8455:1172878] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

I do not know why.

**The code:**

```
@IBAction func onButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    let title = ""
    let style = UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "hello", preferredStyle: style)

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "pass"
    })

    let cancelTitle = "cancel"
    let cancelStyle = UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel
    let cancelHandler:((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = { (action) -> Void in
        print("cancelHandler")
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelTitle, style: cancelStyle, handler: cancelHandler)

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Are you using a UICollectionView elsewhere in your app? This error doesn't seem to apply to the code you pasted. Instead it seems that your UICollectionView cell size is greater than the size of your screen.

Comment: @Patrick Tescher No, I am not using UICollectionView, just a simple application with an button on uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call

```
alert.view.setNeedsLayout()
```

right before

```
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```